# SSRS How to hide details if group field subtotal is zero

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Referencing image, if A=0 how may row 2 (details) be suppressed?

(I added row visibility expression =IIF(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)=0, True, False) to all three rows, the group rows suppress not the details)

Thank you.

[SSRS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPROO.png)

Answer (score 1):

When using an aggegate function like `Sum` without specifying a scope, then the scope will be the "current" scope. In the group header or footer, this will be the group, and the sum will evaluate to what you want. Instead in a details row, the scope will be the details row only, so the value of the sum will be the same as the *Amount* value in the details row (I don't believe that Crystal would calculate differently). Therefore, if you want to use the *Row Visibility*, you will have to make sure that the formula takes the same value for all 3 rows. For example, you could name the TextBox holding the sum something like `VendorTotal`, and for the *Row Visibility* of all 3 rows specify an expression of

```
=(ReportItems!VendorTotal.Value=0)
```

But why hide the individual rows when you can hide the group as a whole?

The *Group Properties* also contain a visibility setting, and you can even specify the condition as an expression using the `Sum` function directly (without referencing a TextBox):

```
=(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the same expression to the details' visibility, does it behave as required?

If not, you might consider adding a column to your SQL statement which is the SUM of the Amount column, then filter your visibility on that column.

eg.

ID | Amount | SUM

1 | 2 | 6

2 | 3 | 6

3 | 1 | 6

Comment: Adding that to the details did not behave as expected..., so simple to do this in crystal reports.

Comment: Ended up cleansing data with sql prior to presenting to report as you suggested. Thank you. Still... seems a lot of work vs. a one liner suppression statement in crystal reports to accomplish the same.